# How do I populate my imageViews efficiently without it crashing with error: Array index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop, uiimageview

I currently have 2 view controllers. The first is an AVCaputureSession responsible for taking pictures. What I am looking to do is for every picture that I take and select the 'Yes' option, to add that image to my 'imageArray' and populate the second view controller, which contains 4 small imageViews.

The code below is what I have got for my second view controller, whereby I am trying to loop through my imageArray and set the images to the imageViews like that. It is crashing with this error:

> fatal error: Array index out of range.

I don't know if there is a better way to do this?

```
if imageArray.count != 0 {

    for im in 0..<imageArray.count {

        imageViewArray[im].image = imageArray[im]

        }
}
```

Comment: The `im` index is out of range for `imageViewArray`.  How did you initialize `imageViewArray` and how big is `imageArray.count`?

Comment: initialised it in viewdidload as so: imageViewArray += [imageView1, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4]
imageArray.count is empty but then is populated as images are added to it

Comment: So, then you must have more than 4 images in `imageArray`.

Comment: ahh right, do you know a more effective way to populate the imageViewArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are crashing because you have more images in `imageArray` than imageViews in `imageViewArray`.  Using the `min` value of the `count` of both arrays will prevent your code from crashing, but you really need to decide what you want your app to do in the case that there are more images than imageViews:

```
if imageArray.count != 0 {

    for im in 0..<min(imageArray.count, imageViewArray.count) {

        imageViewArray[im].image = imageArray[im]

    }
}
```

---

If you want to initialize your imageViews to the images in the `imageArray` or to  `nil` if there aren't enough images in `imageArray` for your imageViews, you can accomplish that in this way:

```
for (index, imageView) in imageViewArray.enumerate() {
    imageView.image = (index < imageArray.count) ? imageArray[index] : nil
}
```

Comment: thanks mate. but now when I hit cancel on the second view, for example, the following code is executed:
  


@IBAction func deleteIV2(sender: AnyObject) {
        if imageView2.image != nil {
            imageView2.image = nil
    if imageArray.count != 0 {
        if imageView1.image == nil {
            imageArray.removeFirst()
        } else {
            imageArray.removeAtIndex(1)
        }
            }
        }
    }
Then what happens is the image in the third image view duplicates itself in the second image view

Comment: You should update your question to provide more information.  Comments aren't a good place for displaying code.

Comment: Before the above loop, initialize image pointers to `nil`:  `for imageView in imageViewArray { imageView.image = nil }`.

Comment: thanks mate, that works really well. But now when I segue back to the view controller before the AVCaptureSession controller, and then back to the view controller which holds the imageViews, they are no longer there. Could there be a reason for this?

Comment: I can't tell without seeing more of your code.  That is another question, though, so you should accept this one and post an additional question.